# How many electrons pased in electrical circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Assume I have electrical circuit that is connected to 5V power supply and current straight is 1A. How to know how many electrons are passed in single point per hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 amp current means 1 coloumb charge per second flows through the circuit.

(1/1.6*10^-19) gives the electrons flowing through a point /second

The above value * the total time (3600 seconds ) will give you the answer.